# Can I modify ofstream before writing to disk?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

```
std::ofstream ofs;
ofs << "Hello, world!" << endl;
```

Now I want to modify the contents of `ofs` to `"Hello, money!"` before writting to disk.
How can I implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `std::endl` IO manipulator will flush the content of the stream buffer, so you will have to change it into a `'\n'` if you later want to process the stream before its content gets flushed.

Also, under the assumption that the reason you actually want to do this is because you need to manipulate the string which is going to be written after formatting, I shall make you aware of the fact that you can use an `std::ostringstream` to exploit the functionality of formatted streaming and gather the result into a string, which you can then manipulate and normally write to a file.

If this was obvious information for you and your use case is more complex, then you will have to write your own stream buffer, as pointed out by @MatsPetersson.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: You should make a class derived from `filebuf` (for the purpose of this discussion `myfilebuf` and use that to construct an `ostream`, which is more accurate than the above.

In the `myfilebuf` you implement `sputbackc`, and have a statemachine to identify "Hello, World!", and replace it with "Hello, Money!", which probably means buffering a second layer until you know which it is.

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way to do generic modification of a fstream. So the solution is to not use an fstream. Instead, write your data to a `stringstream`, and then modify that, and then write that to disk.

```
//write to stringstream
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Hello, world!" << endl;

//modify stringstream
std::string text = ss.str();
text.replace(7, 5, "money");
ss.str(text);

//write stringstream to disk
std::ofstream ofs;
ofs << ss.rdbuf();
```